# Does leaving a lithium-ion battery uncharged for 3-6 months at a time hurt battery life?

Tags: battery, charging

Does leaving a lithium-ion battery uncharged for 3-6 months at a time hurt battery life?

I have seen plenty of questions and articles about the dangers of leaving your cellphone in the charger, but I can't find anything about leaving your devices uncharged.

Comment: Speaking from personal experience. When I know i am not gonna use something for a while, I charge it to 100% and then let it sit. Havent had a problem yet. Cause think about it. Cellphones, laptops, cameras and etc sit on the shelf for months at a time before they are sold. You can take a look at this as well. http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_store_batteries I think as long as its stored in a cool place it will be fine. Heat is the main way to damage a battery.

Comment: @jer3my I've read from your link that you should actually keep it charged at around 40% before putting it in storage.

Comment: True, I kind of skimmed through it. When i read this part "Lithium-ion must be stored in a charged state, ideally 40 percent. This prevents the battery from dropping below 2.50V/cell, at which point the protection circuit could trigger sleep mode." I figured charging to 100% would give it more time to slowly discharge itself. *knocks on wood* So far my batteries seem fine. Next time I'll give this a shot and see how it works out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, leaving a lithium ion battery fully discharged for long periods can destroy the cell's ability to hold a charge. If you are going to be storing batteries for a long time, leave them about half charged.

Answer (score 2):

I live in a hot place and leave the battery after charging to 40% in the fridge well wrapped in Aluminum foil. Seems to help :-)